# Is is possible to make indentation within enumerate item?

Tags: indentation

This is some of my code :

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item {\bfseries For} all $v \in V(D)$ whose weight isn't 0 with $u$ {\bfseries do}\\
\indent {\bfseries If} $l(v) < l(u) + w((u, v))$ \textbf{then}\\
\hspace{2pt} set $l(v) := l(u) + w((u, v))$\\
\indent \indent set $p(v) := u.$
\end{enumerate}
```

what I really want is something like this :

```
 For all v element V(D) whose weight isn't 0 with u do
   If l(v) < l(u) + w(u,v)
      set l(v) := l(u) + w(u,v)
         set p(v) := u
```

but with that code I get :

```
 For all v element V(D) whose weight isn't 0 with u do
   If l(v) < l(u) + w(u,v)
   set l(v) := l(u) + w(u,v)
   set p(v) := u
```

any help appreciated. thanks.

Comment: It is better to use a package like `algorithm`.

Comment: I don't understand about that yet, I appreciate it, but I want something like indentation code.

Comment: You could also use `listings` with with a combination of `morekeywords` and `mathescape`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible solution-- use of `\makebox[length]{}` to serve as a workaround of indentation.

[image]

Code

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{enumitem,amsmath,amssymb}
 \begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item{\bfseries For} all $v \in V(D)$ whose weight isn't 0 with $u$ {\bfseries do}\\
\makebox[0.7cm]{} {\bfseries If} $l(v) < l(u) + w((u, v))$ \textbf{then}\\
\makebox[1.4cm]{} set $l(v) := l(u) + w((u, v))$\\
\makebox[2.1cm]{} set $p(v) := u.$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works like charm, but I've searching about this \makebox code, and I still don't understand what is the function of this makebox, because I don't see any box within the text, except we use the \framebox code, this is the link by the way [http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes]

Comment: I assume, the \makebox code gives "some" spaces first to filled by {some text} then put our text after {some text}, so It looks like indentation, but really this is the smart way I think.

Comment: Ya, you are right the {...} is intentionly left blank to generate some space determined by the length given in [...]. Further, if I can add -- you can define a command as such `\newcommand\myindent[1]{\makebox[#1]{}}` to take one length argument.  Here is the link introducing vairous boxes http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes.